# Angular 2: animation translate3D from the current position

Tags: angular

I have html elements that are positioned using translate3D (I do not have hands on this code)
the initial state is eg translate3d (0px, 220px, 0px)

I want to make an animation on this element, another translateX (-100%)

The problem is that the position of the first translate is not known by the second.

according to the documentation Angular 2, it is possible to get the css value of an object with "Automatic Property Calculation".

Example from the doc angular 2:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

```
animations: [
  trigger('shrinkOut', [
    state('in', style({height: '*'})),
    transition('* => void', [
      style({height: '*'}),
      animate(250, style({height: 0}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

So I try to do the same thing but with translate:

```
    transition('* => swipe-left',[
        style({ transform: '*'}),
        animate(600, style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
    ]),
    transition('* => swipe-right',[
        style({ transform: '*'}),
        animate(600, style({ transform: 'translateX(+100%)' }))
    )]
```

=> It does not work, the translation is from 0 (top of the page). Y is not recovered

Any ideas? How to translate from the current position?

Comment: I have the same problem